# Creating a backstack like Instagram's bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, back-stack

I was wondering how can i create something that is like instagram's backstack.

I have a an app, that has a bottom navigation bar which opens 3 different fragments (`MapFragment`, `HostFragment`, `ProfileFragment`), inside `HostFragment`, i create a new one called `Host2Fragment`, when the user clicks a button:

```
    Tab1          Tab2           Tab3
[MapFragment][HostFragment][ProfileFragment]
                   .
                   .
                   .
             [Host2Fragment]
```

**Some examples:**

NOTE: Tab1/MapFragment is the home fragment

- User is on `Host2Fragment`, pressing back goes back to `HostFragment`

  - pressing back again goes to **Tab1**
- User is on `Host2Fragment`, clicking on **Tab2** goes back to `HostFragment`

Essentially, pressing back, should just peel off all the layers back to the home fragment (Tab1), and update the bottom navigation bar while doing so. I also want to keep the state of the fragments, so that when i click back to it, it should still be in the same state

What i have so far:

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    private val mapFragment: Fragment = MapFragment()
    private val hostFragment: Fragment = HostFragment()
    private val profileFragment: Fragment = ProfileFragment()
    private val fm = supportFragmentManager
    private var activeFragment = mapFragment

    lateinit var toolbar: ActionBar
    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

            when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_map -> {
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(activeFragment).show(mapFragment).commit()
                activeFragment = mapFragment
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_host -> {
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(activeFragment).show(hostFragment).commit()
                activeFragment = hostFragment
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_profile -> {
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(activeFragment).show(profileFragment).commit()
                activeFragment = profileFragment
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, profileFragment, "profileFragment").hide(profileFragment).commit()
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, hostFragment, "hostFragment").hide(hostFragment).commit()
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mapFragment, "mapFragment").commit()

        toolbar = supportActionBar!!
        val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

        //the home Fragment
        bottomNavigation.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_map
    }
}
```

**HostFragment**

```
class HostFragment : Fragment(){
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "HostFragment"
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_host, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val button = view.findViewById(R.id.button) as Button
        button.setOnClickListener{
            Log.d(HostFragment.TAG, "Clicked Host button")
            fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.add(R.id.container, Host2Fragment(), "host2Fragment")?.commit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to play with [setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView#setonnavigationitemreselectedlistener) and have an interface implemented by activity, to let fragment handle back button click first.

Or maybe look into [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/), which makes all of this for you, behind the scenes

Comment: the Navigation Architecture Component that you linked me seems interesting, i will take a look at that. thanks

Comment: @Krizzu so i've implemented the navigation architecture component, and it works well. but my issues is that i have a Google Maps Fragment, and everytime i switch back to that fragment, it reloads the map, and i lose my last position of the map. Is there a way to keep the state of the fragments?

Comment: It depends on your navigation map. Fragments are being replaced when navigating and if they're not in the back stack, they're being destroyed, hence losing a state. Maybe you could save the last position in shared preferences and retrieve it on fragment recreation or pass last map position in navigations arguments?

Comment: This is solution for that have a look here
https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample